# Spring MVC with Webflow or Struts 2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, struts2, spring-webflow

I am starting a new project and must decide between the two.  The team has no experience in either.  Both seem to have similar functionality.  If you have experience in either technology, or both, I would appreciate your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They do have similar functionality.  If you're already using Spring for the project then Spring MVC will probably be a more natural addition, since the configuration style will be the same as Spring.

You might want to look at Raible's [Comparing Web Frameworks](http://static.raibledesigns.com/repository/presentations/ComparingJavaWebFrameworks-ApacheConEU2007.pdf) presentation for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've been heavily involved with projects that use both, and I'd recommend going with Spring MVC.  Most likely, you're already using Spring (if you're not, it would be good to investigate it) and my experience has been that Struts 2 has more goofy quirks than Spring MVC does.

Either isn't a bad choice, and I've used Struts 2 with great success, but Spring MVC is the better framework in most cases, I think.

YMMV